# Let size of flex item depend on its content, thereby respecting its padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following flex-box scenario:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="item1">
       <a href="#">Some Link</a>
   </div>
   <div id="item2">I want about 50% of the window</div>
   <div id="item3">me, too!</div>
</div>
```

with some styling:

```
#container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
} 

#item1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

#item1 a {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20pt;
}

#item2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#item3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Item 1 should be as tall as needed by it's content. Note that there's a link inside with a padding. The flex items size does only consider the height of the text, regardless of the padding.

Item 2 and item 3 should share the rest of the space fifty-fifty.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ochh932y/4/) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are `display:inline` by default and aren't affected by vertical padding...make the link `inline-block`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#item1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#item1 a {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
#item2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
#item3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1">
    <a href="#">Some Link</a>
  </div>
  <div id="item2">I want about 50% of the window</div>
  <div id="item3">me, too!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the problem. However, what happens, if the text inside item 2 or 3 grows. The items will not keep their 50% size. I posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258903/split-space-of-a-fixed-size-container-equally-a-case-for-flexbox).