# split space of a fixed size container equally. a case for flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can a HTML/CSS structure be designed, that splits a fixed size container horizontally into three parts. The first part should be as tall as it's content needs. The second and the third part would share the remaining space fifty-fifty - regardless of their contents. If the size of their contents exceeds this limitation, the section should be scrollable.

The HTML part of it is trivial: A `div` container with three `div`'s as children.

I tried to solve this with flexbox - however there might be a better choice for this:

The css part:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#item1 { flex: 0 0 auto; }
#item2 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
#item3 { flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

Unfortunately this only works if the contents of item 2 or 3 is not too large.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vjktkfa/1/) for a bit more detailed implementation of the problem.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#item1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: Bisque;
}
#item2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: DarkOrange;
}
#item3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: MediumAquaMarine;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1">I'll be as tall as my content takes.</div>
  <div id="item2">From the rest, I'll take exactly 50%. No matter how short or long my content is. If needed there should be scrollbars.</div>
  <div id="item3">I'll take the other 50% of the rest!
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
    <br>right?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use flex. Here's a little improvement for your code. Item1 doesn't need to have a flex rule and item2 and item3 will have `flex: 1`.

I also added the `overflow-y: auto;` rule to make it scrollable.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2vjktkfa/2/)

```
#item1 {background-color: Bisque ; }
#item2 { flex: 1; background-color: DarkOrange ; overflow-y: auto;}
#item3 { flex: 1; background-color: MediumAquaMarine ; overflow-y: auto;}
```

Comment: nice, this works. So "0 0 auto" seems to be the default then. It looks like the crucial part were the other 'auto' attributes. I guess flex: 1 1 equals flex: 1 furthermore. thanks.

Comment: bonus: what would one do, if the proportion between item2 and 3 could be resized by the mouse. trivial addition or: another post?

Comment: Sounds like another post :)